# Use wheights on neuralnet mlp r

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network as follows:

```
neuralnet(a ~ b + c + d + e ,data = df1, hidden = c(10,10), lifesign = "full")
```

it works fine, but I have to correct the skewedness of the df which has 99% falses for 1% true. nnet() function had a wheights vector for doing that, does neuralnet() has something similar? If it doesnt, how else could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this for now, but still interested on any tools the package provides:

```
factor.list <- lapply(1:factor, function(x){df1[df1$a == 0,]})
factor.df <- do.call(rbind, factor.list)
model2 <- neuralnet(a ~ b + c + d + e ,data = rbind(df1,factor.df), hidden = c(10,10), lifesign = "full")
```

Where "factor" is the proportion between 1s and 0s